# How to auth my app with Google LogIn?

Tags: java, android, api

I have googled some info but still not undersant exactly how to auth my app with my server side.

I have <kbd>Google LogIn</kbd> button, as far as i understand when i click it, i sent request token, then i get back acsess token and can use it to get info from Google API,

but issue is what i should to do to auth the current user with my DB? It is ok that i get a acsess from google to use API, but what about my DB, what i should to do next, how i can concatenate it google logIn and my DB?

Could anybody help me to understand consept of auth and registration user in my DB with <kbd>Google LogIn</kbd> button?

Comment: which server side technology you are using?

Comment: Sorry, but i am not familiar enough with Python to help with it. :(

Comment: @RanHassid but i think it is doesn't matter whith technology is, i just try understend the concept... After i get acsses token from google what i should to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the basic concept is the following:

1. Do the Google Login with the option to request an `IdToken`
2. Send the IdToken to your server
3. [Check if the IdToken is valid](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) by using one of the [Google API Client libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/) (here is [one for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/))
4. After the token is verified you'll receive a payload which includes the `userId` - you can use this userId to identify the user in your backend.

Following a picture of the whole procedure described above:

[image: Google Sign-In with Server]

See the corresponding [Blog-Post](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2016/01/using-google-sign-in-with-your-server.html) as well.

Comment: greate! Thanks a lot! Maybe do you know how to get token from google? Because in code we just have a listener `onSussces()` , but how to get token to send it the server?

Comment: Once the login is done you'll receive a `GoogleSignInResult` in `onActivityResult`. Check if the login is successful via `googleSignInResult.isSuccess()` and get the IdToken afterwards via `googleSignInResult.getSignInAccount().getIdToken()`. This is the token you wanna send to your server.

Comment: Sorry last one)) as far as i understand i should use this tokenId every time when i make a request to server, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

This might help with your own oauth2 server
http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/

Comment: but i think it is doesn't matter whith technology is, i just try understend the concept... After i get acsses token from google what i should to do next?